# Parse multidimensional array from database into XML file (parsing error)

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I want to parse a multidimensional array into a xml file. However my xml file shows one long string with all items in it instead of the proper layout.

My code:

This array is only 1 out of 3000+ arrays I want to put into my xml file.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [line_item_id] => 23
            [order_id] => 9
            [type] => product
            [line_item_label] => 10101001
            [quantity] => 1.00
            [created] => 1361126884
            [changed] => 1361126884
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [context] => Array
                        (
                            [product_ids] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 6
                                )

                            [add_to_cart_combine] => 1
                            [show_single_product_attributes] => 0
                            [display_path] => node/15
                            [entity] => Array
                                (
                                    [entity_type] => node
                                    [entity_id] => 15
                                    [product_reference_field_name] => field_products
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

The function:

```
function array_to_xml($array, $xml_options) {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                if(!is_numeric($key)){
                    $subnode = $xml_options->addChild("$key");
                    array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
                }else{
                    $subnode = $xml_options->addChild("item$key");
                    array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
                }
            }else {
                $xml_options->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
            }
        }
    }
```

The code for putting it into an xml file:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Products></Products>");
$data = get_data();
array_to_xml($data,$xml);
$xml_file = $xml->asXML('products.xml');
```

This just outputs one long string in my xml file. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I found out that some data in my database uses 0 as a key. However my code doesnt seem to change it into something else. I will look into this.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual source and made sure that the browser does not render your XML as HTML (and ignores unknown tags)?

Comment: @ThW I found out that my database stored data within a .bin file. Within this data was a key (0), which is not allowed in xml. PHP didnt recognize this as a number, so I had to make a check where I made a new value in the array, drop the array and then recreate it. Ik works properly now.